# Default stack size in SystemC

Tags: systemc

Does anyone knows why default stack size in SystemC is equal to `0x50000` if we don't use POSIX Threads (and at the same time use Cygwin) and `0x20000` on other case?

Answer (score 0):

See src/sysc/kernel/sc_constants.h

```
const int SC_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE   =
#if !defined(SC_USE_PTHREADS) && \
    ( defined(__CYGWIN32__) || defined(__CYGWIN32) )
  0x50000;
#else
  0x20000;
#endif
```